# Angular templates not loading after switching to Jade

Tags: angularjs, pug, yeoman

I recently switched my Angular project from JavaScript to CoffeeScript (which went fine), and then from HTML to Jade. I'm still trying to work out one of the Jade kinks. I'm using Yeoman.

When I load any particular page of my project, I just get a blank screen. If I view the source it contains what appears to be the normal content of my `index.html`.

What's really confusing is that if I navigate to the template that the page is trying to load (e.g. `http://localhost:9000/views/file-uploads/index.html`), the template is there and loads just fine.

So something along the way is getting screwed up, I just don't know what, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Any ideas?

Here's my [Gruntfile.coffee](http://pastebin.com/uWVnnP9H)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the tool I used, `html2jade`, wrapped all my templates in `html` and `body` tags, unnecessarily. For whatever reason this caused problems. Once I took the `html` and `body` tags out of my converted Jade files, everything worked fine.